# gridlib cell format in python

Tags: python, format, wxpython

I am using a gridlib within wxpanel. I am creating the following grid:

```
    myGrid = gridlib.Grid(panel)
    myGrid.CreateGrid(120, 9)
```

I want to be able to change the format of the 5th column and make it a dropdown (meaning the options the user can enter are pre-defined). Is there a way to do that ? Basically, I am looking for a call like the following:
myGrid.setFormat(5, wx.Dropdown, ("I", "you", "they")) or something like that.
Is that possible or do I need to look for a different grid object in python. If so, what is that one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The wxPython demo includes a grid editor for creating custom editors / renderers. In that demo, it shows how to add a dropdown (combobox) called the GridCellChoiceEditor. I would recommend taking a look at that and integrating it into your own application.